# Can I look upp a key in a tcl dict when having the value? Reverse lookup

Tags: dictionary, tcl, lookup

I have an tcl dict containing keys and their values. Is there a way to do a "reverse lookup" eg looking for the value, and retrieving the key.
I know that this does not sound like state of the art programming, but the dict already exists in my code and I would not like to recreate it the other way around just because of this one time I need it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `dict filter` command. Values can repeat, so you should expect more than one single key.

```
set d [dict create a b c d e b]
# note that the "b" value is repeated for keys "a" and "e"

dict filter $d value b
-> a b e b
```

So you can use something like this:

```
set lookupVal b
dict for {k v} [dict filter $d value $lookupVal] {
    lappend keys $k
}

puts $keys
-> a e
```

Comment: use `dict keys [dict filter $d value $val]`.

Comment: Right! I just wrote on the fly :)

Answer (score 2):

If your values are unique, the dirty-hack way to get the key for a particular value is this:

```
set theKey [dict get [lreverse $theDict] $theValue]
```

I wouldn't particularly recommend it as it's a type-buster, but it will do the right thing. (If you've got the same value several times, this will return the key for the *first* instance.)

Note that you still retain the original dictionary in `$theDict` if you do this. (Well, assuming you're satisfied with Tcl's detailed type semantics when behind-the-scenes type conversions are happening.)

---

If you're thinking about doing this more than very occasionally, consider keeping a reversed dictionary around alongside the original so that you can do the lookup rapidly. This applies even if you use the `dict keys [dict filter …]` solution; linear scans of anything large can definitely slay you otherwise.